# Setting User Agent for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

could you please help with setting User Agent for AVPlayer?

I have a following code:

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")

    var headers: [String:String] = ["User-Agent": "myagent"]
    let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(url!, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset)
    player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(playerItem)
    player.play()
```

It doesn't work. How I can set User Agent in a right way in Swift?

Comment: Please Refer this link it might help :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899128/how-to-play-video-with-cookies-content-in-ios-using-avplayer-in-swift?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 11):

it is really very simple in Swift 2.3

```
let headerFields: [String:String] = ["User-Agent":"myua"]
let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL:url!, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headerFields])
```

Comment: There's also a `typealias` for `[String: String]` as `HTTPHeaders`, so you can use: `let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["User-Agent": "Some user agent"]`

Comment: @oleynikd, `HTTPHeaders` is part of Alamofire library, right? Anyone checking this answer `AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey` is not public API, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided an *officially*-supported way of doing this as of iOS 16 (as well as macOS 13, iPadOS 16, tvOS 16, and watchOS 9) using `AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey`.

You can specify it as an option when creating an `AVURLAsset`, like this:

```
let asset:AVURLAsset?
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    asset           = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: [AVURLAssetHTTPUserAgentKey: "MyCustomUserAgent"])
} else {
    asset           = AVURLAsset(url: url)
}
```

Details can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlassethttpuseragentkey