# How to play video with cookies content in iOS using AVPlayer in Swift?

Tags: cookies, swift3, video-streaming, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have used the below implementation to play a video with cookies content from the server, but it shows play icon with cross line. I have refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722166/how-to-play-protected-video-content-in-ios-using-avplayer) and do following implementation in swift. but I didn't get any output :(

```
func showVideo(url: String) {
  let videoURL = NSURL(string: url)
  var cookiesArray = [HTTPCookie]()
  guard let cookieArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: 
  Constants.Object.kCookie) as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else { 
  return }

  for cookieProperties in cookieArray {
    if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
      cookiesArray.append(cookie)
    }
  } 
  let cookieArrayOptions = [AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey: cookiesArray]
  let assets = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL! as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
  let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
  videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

  self.playerController.player =  self.videoPlayer 
  self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
  self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  self.playerController.player?.play()
 }
```

Please help me on that, what is wrong in that implementation.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through so many ways finally I have got the solution which worked for me :

```
     func showVideo(url: String) {
      let videoURL = NSURL(string: url)
      let cookiesArray = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! //Stored Cookies of your request
      let values = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)// Returns a dictionary of header fields corresponding to a provided array of cookies.ex.["Cookie":"your cookies values"]
      let cookieArrayOptions = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": values]
      let assets = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL! as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
      let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
      videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

      self.playerController.player =  self.videoPlayer 
      self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
      self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      self.playerController.player?.play()
     }
```

Comment: I was getting a crash when i followed this answer on iOS 13.5.1. 

I was able to fix it by skipping the call to requestHeaderFields.

In short it looks like this:

Comment: var options: [String: Any] = [:]
        if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
            options[AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey] = cookies
        }
        
        let asset: AVURLAsset = .init(url: url, options: options)
        let item: AVPlayerItem = .init(asset: asset)